# magento admin giving error You don't have authorization to view this page. HTTP ERROR 403

Tags: magento, http-status-code-403

My magento admin is not accessible,when i type url in chrome its says You don't have authorization to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403.please help me to resolve the issue.My frontend is working fine.....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like file permission issue. Check if your web server has the rights to read and execute on that Magento folder.

Ref URL: 
[You don't have permission to access /magento/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30645696/you-dont-have-permission-to-access-magento)